# Sent emails in the sent items folder but never received on Exchange 2016 (Windows 10)

Tags: microsoft-outlook, exchange, microsoft-outlook-2016

So i configured my Exchange server right with the Imap, Pop & SMTP settings then set parameters for the DNS server (with a pointer to the address of the server) but i neither can receive nor send emails the mailbox is actually not found when someone sends to it an email, and when i send an email from my outlook account using that Exchange server the email goes to the Sent Items but is never received by the destination recipient. I tried to configure the Mail (Control Panel) to add a new Outlook profile but it doesn't pass either.
What might be missing in my Config in this case ?

Thank you.

UPDATE Get-Queue returns the following :

```
LED=451 4.4.397 Error communicating with target host 421 4.4.2
```

[Get-Queue CMD results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/S462S.png)

With a message count of `10`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you have issues when only sending or receiving emails from external users? Or from all the users?

To confirm if your messages are stuck in message queue, please try `Get-Queue | ft Identity, MessageCount, LastError -AutoSize`(**MessageCount** and **LastErro**r), if there were some messages stuck in queue, you could try to restart **Microsoft Exchange Transport Service** on the mail server to see if the issue has any difference.
[image]

Besides, you could also check the status of your messages via **MessageTracking Log** to see if you have already successfully send or receive it.

```
Get-MessageTrackingLog -Sender <Sender's email address> -Recipients <Recipient's email address> -MessageSubject "<MessageSubject>" -Start "<Send time>"
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to restart Microsoft Exchange Transport Service on the mail server? It is also suggested to restart your mail server to see if the issue has any difference.

> LED=451 4.4.397 Error communicating with target host 421 4.4.2.

I found that the 4.4.2 error message you mentioned is not the same as your screenshot in which shows 4.2.1. Are there any mistakes?

I did some research about these error message and found that the 4.4.2 error might be related to your network or Message rate limits and throttling, for more information, please check this article: [Temporary delivery failures](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/Exchange/mail-flow/non-delivery-reports-and-bounce-messages/non-delivery-reports-and-bounce-messages?view=exchserver-2019#temporary-delivery-failures). And about the 4.2.1 error, please check [this possible cause](https://supertekboy.com/2020/03/22/improperly-configured-dns-causes-internal-mail-to-hairpin-via-firewall/). Besides, to futher confirm your issue, you could try to send test outbound via [Microsoft Remote Connectivitiy Analyse](https://testconnectivity.microsoft.com/tests/OutboundSMTP/input) for more information.